# Cobb-Douglas Lagrange Minimization Question

Tags: optimization, economics

I am having trouble with the following Cobb-Douglas cost minimization problem. Given the following Cobb-Douglas production function $f(K,L)=y=K^{0.5}L^{0.25}$. The price of labor and capital are given by w and r respectively so I want to minimize $rK+wL$.

After I set up my first order conditions:

$L=rK+wL+\lambda[y-K^{0.5}L^{0.25}]$

1. $r=0.5\lambda K^{0.25}L^{-0.5}$
2. $w=0.25 \lambda K^{0.5}L^{-0.75}$
3. $Y=K^{0.5}L^{0.25}$

In this case I am having problems solving for lambda. I was able to optimize $L^{*}=(\frac{r}{2w})^{\frac{2}{3}}y^{\frac{4}{3}}$ and $K^{*}=(\frac{2w}{r})^{\frac{1}{3}}y^{\frac{4}{3}}$. Any help or insights into solving for lambda the Lagrange multiplier will be greatly appreciated cause I have no idea how to start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forming the lagrangian as

$$
L=r K+w L + \lambda(y-K^a L^b)
$$

we have the stationarity condition

$$
\nabla L = 0= \left\{
\begin{array}{l}
 r-a \lambda  K^{a-1} L^b \\
 w-b \lambda  K^a L^{b-1} \\
 y-K^a L^b \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

and solving for $(K,L,\lambda)$ we get

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rcl}
 K^* & = & \left(\frac{aw}{br}\right)^{\frac{b}{a+b}} y^{\frac{1}{a+b}}\\
L^* & = & \left(\frac{b r}{a w}\right)^{\frac{a}{a+b}}y^{\frac{1}{a+b}}\\
\lambda^* & = &  \left(\frac{r}{ay}\right)^{\frac{a}{a+b}}\left(\frac{w}{by}\right)^{\frac{b}{a+b}}y^{\frac{1}{a+b}}
\end{array}
\right.
$$